# How can I store a variable as the key of an @AppStorage variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

> So I wanted to make the switch to @AppStorage in my app but I'm troubled with a specific issue.

> For the key of the @AppStorage I would like to use a variable that I already have but I can not do that but I used to find a way to do it with User Defaults as the following will show.

```
 @State var isSignedUp = false
```

> So I would initialise the User Defaults first as a @State var then in the .onAppear I would use the key as my id variable:

```
isSignedUp = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: id)
```

> What I am asking is how can I do this with @AppStorage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can separate `id` dependent subview and initialize `AppStorage` property wrapper dynamically.

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct IsSignedView: View {

    @AppStorage var isSigned: Bool     // << declare

    init(id: String) {
        // Initialize with default value and dynamic key from argument
        self._isSigned = AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, id)
    }

    // ... other dependent code here
}
```

Comment: Ok so what I did was I used your variable declaration then in my previous view where I present the view with its variables I put in the Appstorage(wrappedValue: false, id) and it was working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@AppStorage("IsSigned") var isSigned = false
```

Comment: No there is no way I can use that, as I said I need to use the variable as this a view in a forEach where there are multiple id's not just one that I can use.